# Run wine commands from Python 3.6 on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, wine

I am trying to write a script in Python which opens `wine` and then sends code to the `wine` terminal to open a `.exe` program. The `.exe` program is also command driven.

I can open `wine`, but I can't get any further:

```
import shlex, subprocess

line = "/usr/bin/open -n -a /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app"
line2 = '''cd /Applications/application/ && wine application.exe /h1 
/k0 Z:/Users/myname/Desktop/File.TXT''' 
line = shlex.split(line)
p1 = subprocess.Popen(line)
p1.stdin.write(line2.encode())
```

The above doesn't work, `wine` doesn't seem to receive line2, although

```
/usr/bin/open -n -a /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app
```

by itself is fine (it opens `Wine` but nothing else.)

I'm pretty confused about what the next step should be. I would like to avoid additional dependencies if possible, because it seems simple.

Comment: ``shlex`` doesn't seem to keep new line chars, you'll need to deliminate the commands in the shell some how (as they are now all on one line). I would suggest using `&&` between the commands.

Comment: that's a start, thanks for noticing that, however it still doesn't seem to work, even subbing line for  '''/usr/bin/open -n -a /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app && cd /Applications/application/ ''' doesn't even open wine, whereas '''/usr/bin/open -n -a /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app''' will

Comment: Does the `Wine Stable.app` return when you call it or block the terminal? If it's blocking then the other commands won't run until it's done.

Comment: how can I tell and how can I resolve the issue if it's blocking?

Comment: Try running the same command in a normal terminal and see if the terminal keeps working while the app is open or waits for it to close. If the program is blocking the terminal you can either have two calls to ``subprocess.Popen`` or you can use a single ``&`` rather than a double ``&&`` to fork the program into the background.

Comment: terminal keeps working after wine is opened, but also -one point that might need clarifying- I am opening wine from the terminal, but every command afterwards should be sent to the wine terminal. This probably means I need two processes, but how do I address wine after I've opened it? This is my main issue.

Comment: In that case you don't want to give the other lines to the starting terminal but rather to the ``stdin`` of ``p1``. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin

Comment: I've added `line2 = '''cd /Applications/application/ &&
wine application.exe /h1 /k0 Z:/Users/myname/Desktop/File.TXT''' p1.stdin.write(line2.encode()) after the code, still no dice

Comment: Can you update the question to match the current state of the problem? (Also use the backtick ` to make code in comments (it's below the ~ on US keyboards)).

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I haven't used wine in a while or a mac, is ``Wine Stable.app`` a new window that needs typing in?

Comment: yes, it is essentially its own terminal window

Comment: You'll need to look at it's documentation to see how to give it parameters then (as it's not waiting on stdin). See if it has a command line mode or can be passes a script file.

Comment: https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS_FAQ#How_to_create_shortcut.2C_launcher.2C_or_.app_to_start_a_given_.exe.3F this is as far as I've gotten, but I'm totally stumped from here. I could alter the code to run the applescript potentially.

Answer (score 1):

The following has worked for me in many cases (on Linux):

```
import subprocess

command = 'echo "echo foo && echo bar" | wine cmd > std_out.txt 2> std_error.txt &'
subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True)
```

(I believe `wine` is also available as a command on MacOS, just like that. Please correct me if I am wrong.)

The command fires up a Windows/DOS-like shell (`wine cmd`). You can actually type `wine cmd` into your Linux shell and hit enter - you'll find yourself in a DOS shell. The next step is to get commands into the DOS shell. I do this by piping them into it as a string. In my example, I run two commands: `echo foo` and `echo bar`. The initial `echo` writes the command string to stdout, the following `|` opens a pipe and forwards the string into the DOS shell.

Besides, once you send commands to the DOS shell, keep in mind that it expects Windows paths (when you change directories etc). I.e. you must translate your Unix paths into Windows paths before you send them into the DOS shell. You can automatically convert your path on a command line like this ...

```
winepath -w /home/ 2> /dev/null
```

... resulting in `Z:\home\` (for example). Alternatively, the following Python snipped will do the same for you:

```
def convert_unix_path_to_windows_path(in_path):
    cmd = ['winepath', '-w', in_path]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
    return out.decode('utf-8').strip()
```